# Change Flutter Crop Default Image Size

Tags: flutter

I'm using crop_your_image package from flutter to help with my cropping page when user either choose or take an image.

The problem is the picture is full screen meanwhile the crop area is small, so my user have to zoom out to crop a certain broader area and resulting bad user experience.

How to make the crop area full screen also or make the picked / taken image is fully zoomed out ?

Here's my current code:

```
Visibility(
visible: _croppedData == null,
replacement: _croppedData != null
    ? SizedBox(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Image.memory(
          _croppedData!,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      )
    : const SizedBox.shrink(),
child: Crop(
  initialSize: 0.7,
  controller: _controller,
  image: pickedImage!,
  cornerDotBuilder: (size, edgeAlignment) =>
  const SizedBox.shrink(),
  onCropped: (cropped) async {
    convertImage(cropped);
  },
  aspectRatio: widget.cropRatio,
  interactive: true,
),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) package instead.

Following is the code snippet from my app, Please edit it according to your requirements.

```html
 static Future<CroppedFile?> _cropImage(String path) async {
    return await ImageCropper().cropImage(
      sourcePath: path,
      aspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 3.375, ratioY: 2.125),
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],
      uiSettings: [
        AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
          toolbarColor: AppColors.primary,
          toolbarWidgetColor: AppColors.secondary,
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          lockAspectRatio: false,
        ),
        IOSUiSettings(title: 'Cropper'),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Make sure you have added the activity in `AndroidManifest` file